# Ssh X11 forwarding very slow using Xshell

Tags: xorg, matlab

My server is Ubuntu 12.10

And my client is Windows 7 64bit

Now I am using Xshell to connect my server via ssh

But after I forwarding X11, it's take a long time!!

after I enter

```
$matlab -nodesktop
```

it's almost take 5~10 mins to ready for use

I have found some speed up issue on the web but it's work on MAC not on windows(Xshell)!

following is solution for mac and it's worked perfect!

```
ssh -c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -XC username@host
```

But when I use Xshell it's always think  `-c arcfour,blowfish-cbc -XC username`is my username!

Is there any other way to make it faster?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should read ssh manpage.
-C (capital) enable zlib compression, this means server and client will spend time doing 
   data compression/decompression. Since you want to speed up and - i guess - bandwith is 
   not a problem you should not use it

-c arcfour,blowfish-cbc is to specify a different cipher to encrypt. while those cipher 
   could be faster,they are known to be insecure. Unless you know what you are doing you 
   should not use them

Last, those are option for ssh not xshell which is a totally different program